# How to model the probability of a system failing if any of its subsystems fails?

Tags: probability, random-variables, gamma-distribution

Suppose I have a system that consists of $m$ independent subsystems. The work expectancy for each of these subsystems is a random variable, let's say $X_i$, where $i$ denotes the $i$-th subsystem. Each of these variables has the same exponential distribution (with, let's say $\lambda$ as the parameter. Now, my system only works as long as all the subsystems work.

Now, I want to model a random variable $Z$ such that it denotes the work expectancy of the system of a whole and find its CDF. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order for us to give an appropriate answer, we would like to see your thoughts on how to solve this. What topics studied recently? Is the parameter the mean or the rate? What level of course. Please edit your question. See some clues in my partial Answer. This is an important problem for learning probability and for applications. It has several worthwhile steps, and I hope you will understand them all by the time you finish with this. Please update the Question ASAP, and leave a Comment if you need more clues.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the distribution of $Z = \min(Y_i)$. 
The system "dies" when the first subsystem "dies."

If the
reliability function of $Y_i$ is 
$$1 - F_i(t) = R_i(t) = P(X_i > t),$$
then can you write the formula for the reliability function
for $t > 0$? Next, do you see how to express the reliability function $R_Z(t)$ of $Z$ in terms of the $R_i(t)?$

The 'parameter' of the exponential distribution can be either
the rate or the mean. Your use of $\lambda$ suggests you are
using the rate, but you need to clarify that. It makes a
difference when you write $P(X_i > t).$

Maybe start with the case $m = 2.$
You can find that
much on this site by searching for page 580279.
Then see how easy it is to generalize to $m$ subsystems.

Once you have the
reliability curve of $Z$, use it to find the CDF of $Z$, and
differentiate to get the density function of $Z$ (easy calculus).

As another clue I am going to show you the results of a simulation
that has $m = 3$ independent subsystems, each with parameter $\lambda = 1$ (the only
case in which it doesn't matter whether the parameter is mean
or rate). The histogram shows the results of a million simulated
experiments. The density curve is consistent with $E(Z) = 1/3$
and should be a special case of the density curve of $Z$ as you
derive it.

```
 m = 10^6;  y1 = rexp(m);  y2 = rexp(m);  y3 = rexp(m)
 z = pmin(y1, y2, y3)
 mean(z)
 ## 0.3337452 # simulation of E(Z)
 sd(z)
 ## 0.3334918 # simulation of SD(Z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say

$P(X_i>t)=e^{-\lambda t}$, random variables $ x_i $ are independent, $\Rightarrow P(X>t)=(e^{-\lambda t})^m=e^{-m\lambda t}$

$\Rightarrow P(X\le t) = 1-e^{-m\lambda t}$

See [For rate = 3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exponential%20distribution%2C%20rate%20%3D%203)